# Optimization in Z3: removing the epsilons

Tags: optimization, z3

Optimizing a real value subject to strict constraints (e.g. `max x s.t. x < 4`) produces the `epsilon` value in the call to `Z3_optimize_get_upper`.

In the example above, the returned value would be `4 - epsilon`.

Is there a way to get rid of the epsilon, that is, instantiate it to any particular value? E.g. set it to `0`, or `1` or `0.1`?

Thanks!

EDIT:

In the code of `opt_context.cpp`, I see that the constant called `epsilon` is created:

`if (!eps.is_zero()) {
   expr* ep = m.mk_const(symbol("epsilon"), m_arith.mk_int());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I have figured it out: using `substitute` with a further call to `simplify` seems to do the trick.